# Using a newly assigned column in a `groupby` statement? (method chaining with Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm an R (`dplyr`) user who's learning how to clean data using `pandas`. I am practicing using the wind turbines dataset, and I would like to be able to return a data frame with the count of manufacturers per year in British Colombia since the year 2000.

The chunk below returns an error `NameError: name 'year' is not defined`. Is there a way to pipe a newly generated column, `year` in this case, into a `groupby` statement within one chain?

```
import pandas as pd

wind_raw = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-10-27/wind-turbine.csv"
)

(
    wind_raw
    .loc[:,['province_territory', 'manufacturer', 'commissioning_date']]
    .assign(year = wind_raw.commissioning_date.str.replace(r'(\d{4})(\/\d{4})*', r'\1'))
    .assign(year = lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row.year))
    .query('province_territory == "British Columbia" and year >= 2000')
    .groupby(wind_raw.manufacturer, year)
    .size()
)
```

Comment: @ScottBoston thanks! could you elaborate on how I might use `pipe` in this case?

Comment: please be careful with your tags, I see you're using pandas and not `r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it, you only have to change the `groupby` parameters:

```
(
wind_raw
.loc[:,['province_territory', 'manufacturer', 'commissioning_date']]
.assign(year = wind_raw.commissioning_date.str.replace(r'(\d{4})(\/\d{4})*', r'\1'))
.assign(year = lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row.year))
.query('province_territory == "British Columbia" and year >= 2000')
.groupby(["manufacturer", "year"])
.size()
)
```

**Output**

```
manufacturer  year      
Enercon       2009-01-01    34
              2019-01-01     4
GE            2017-01-01    61
Leitwind      2010-01-01     1
Senvion       2017-01-01    10
Vestas        2011-01-01    48
              2012-01-01    79
              2014-01-01    55
```

Also, there are a couple thing that can be simplified:

```
(
wind_raw[['province_territory', 'manufacturer']]
.assign(year = wind_raw.commissioning_date.str.extract("(\d{4})").astype(int))
.query('province_territory == "British Columbia" and year >= 2000')
.groupby(["manufacturer", "year"])
.size()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, you can specify your column selection in the `groupby` method as strings: `.groupby(["manufacturer", "year"])` (we use a list to groupby multiple columns).

And if you're interested, here's an extra tidbit:

```
.assign(year = lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row.year))
```

Passing a function to the `assign` method does not pass each row to the function. It actually passes the dataframe in its current form.

---

Moreover, you can use some fun method chaining even within the `assign` method

```
.assign(
    year = (wind_raw.commissioning_date
        .str.replace(r'(\d{4})(\/\d{4})*', r'\1'))
        # use the pipe method to pass the regex extracted column to `pd.to_datetime`
        .pipe(pd.to_datetime)) 
)
```

Comment: this is awesome, thank you so much for your insights!